# Dependency Injection with typescript and express using classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, dependency-injection

How we can use the concept of dependency injection in route file and added in server file?

I tried to use dependency injection in my node project but I don't think that I am on the right path.  I am trying to inject my `UserService` into my `AppRouter`.  My registration method was previously `static` but I changed it to a `public` method because a `static` member does not allow me to inject the dependency.

First of all `this.userService.UserRegistrationService` is showing me error `undefined`. Please suggest the right way to do this as I am new to express and node.

Route File

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import { API } from ".././utilities/api";
import UserService from '../api/services/UserService';
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
import validationMw from '../api/middlewares/request_validation';
import UserDao from '../api/requests/userDto';
let cors = require('cors');
//let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
class AppRouter {

  private userService: UserService;
  public router: express.Router;
  public userObj: any;

  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    this.router = express();
    this.router.use(cors());
    this.AddMiddlewares();
    this.AddRoutes();
   
    this.userService =  userService;
  }

  // Add all middlewares here that will get request before routes.
  AddMiddlewares(): void { //  Used to parse req.body into json object

    this.router.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    //this.router.use(LogsService.LogRequest);
  }

  AddRoutes(): void {
    console.log(API.RegistrationEmployee);
    this.router.post(API.RegistrationEmployee, this.userService.UserRegistrationService);
  }
}

export default new AppRouter(new UserService).router;
```

User Services Class

```
import { Request, Response } from "express-serve-static-core";
import { isNullOrUndefined, isNull } from "util";
import { logger } from "../../utilities/logger";
import UserController from "../controllers/userController";
import { ProjectConstants, ErrorCodes } from "../../utilities/config";
import {
  ReasonPhrases,
  StatusCodes,
  getReasonPhrase,
  getStatusCode,
} from "http-status-codes";
import ResponseService from "../services/ResponseService";

export default class UserService {

  private userController: UserController;
  
  constructor(userController?: UserController) {
      this.userController = userController;
  }  

  public async UserRegistrationService(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.log(434);
    // UtilityMethods.ConsoleLog("UserRegisterService - BODY", req.body);
    logger.info("UserRegistration- function call " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    
    await this.userController.registration(req.body)
      .then((data: any) => {
        // UtilityMethods.ConsoleJSON("03 GetCategoryService", data);
        ResponseService.SendSucessResponse(req, res, data, ErrorCodes.OK);
      })
      .catch(function (err: any) {
        ResponseService.SendErrorResponse(req, res, err);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any one who can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have designed some of these classes to take dependencies in their constructors, but you need to make sure that you are *providing* the dependencies when you call `new`.

You are missing the parentheses after `UserService` in this line `new AppRouter(new UserService).router`.  It needs to be `new UserService()` in order to fix the syntax error.  But you will still have runtime errors.

This block of code right here is a problem:

```
class UserService {
    private userController: UserController;

    constructor(userController?: UserController) {
        this.userController = userController;
    }
```

`private userController: UserController` means that `this.userController` must always be a `UserController`.  But `constructor(userController?: UserController)` means that you can construct it with a `UserController` or without one.  If you call `new UserService()` with no arguments, then `this.userController` is `undefined` and that's not ok.  Doing things like this `await this.userController.registration(req.body)` will give you errors if `this.userController` is `undefined`.

In order for your `UserService` to work, you **must** provide a `UserController` argument to the constructor.

We change the `constructor` so that it is no longer optional:

```
    constructor(userController: UserController) {
```

But now we have a problem with the line where you create the `AppRouter` because you need to be providing a `UserController`.

This won't work:

```
export default new AppRouter(new UserService()).router;
```

I'm not sure how you instantiate the `UserController` (does it require any arguments?), so this might not be right.  But it should look something like this:

```
const userController = new UserController();

export default new AppRouter(new UserService(userController)).router;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and i have also solved this problem after go though again ,actually  by using new, we have to pass each instance of object those are used in constructor . So for avoid this i used the concept of typedi and container in node js